# Wordpress Nav Menu Child Pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a customize theme for wordpress , when i add a page it automatically shows in the menu , i have added child pages which i want to show in the menu too , but the menu is expanding to 1 level only , i want to show 3 levels like

Top Navigation Menu

Product -> Hardware -> DELL -> Laptops
                            -> Desktops

Something like that. The code which is generating the menu is below please help me in it

```
    <section id="nav-container">
    <section class="container_12">
    <section class="grid_12"> 
        <!-- #nav start -->
        <nav id="nav">
          <ul>
            <li><span class="nav-icon icon-home"></span> <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">Home</a></li>
            <?php

        $wpmenu = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'page','post_status' => 'publish', 'post_parent' => '0','order' => 'ASC','orderby' => 'menu_order'));
        $myi = 1;
        if($wpmenu->have_posts()): while($wpmenu->have_posts()): $wpmenu->the_post();
        $icon = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "icon", TRUE);
        ?>  
            <li><span class="nav-icon icon-<?php echo $icon;?>"></span>
            <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php
            $submenu2 = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page' AND $wpdb->posts.post_parent = '".get_the_ID()."' ORDER BY menu_order ASC";
            if($menu3 = $wpdb->get_results($submenu2, OBJECT))
            {
                echo "<ul>";
                foreach($menu3 as $menu4)
                {
                ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($menu4->ID); ?>"><?php echo $menu4->post_title; ?></a></li>
                <?php
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "</li>";   
            }
            ?>
            <?php
            $myi++;
            endwhile; endif;
            wp_reset_query();
            ?>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- #nav end --> 

        <!-- responsive navigation start -->
        <select id="nav-responsive">
          <option value="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">Home</option>
          <?php
        $active = "";
        $wpmenu = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'page','post_status' => 'publish', 'post_parent' => '0','order' => 'ASC','orderby' => 'menu_order'));
        if($wpmenu->have_posts()): while($wpmenu->have_posts()): $wpmenu->the_post();
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_title();?>
          </option>
          <?php
          endwhile; endif;
          wp_reset_query();
          ?>
        </select>
        <!-- responsive navigation end -->

        <section id="search-box">
          <form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" role="search" method="get" id="searchform">
            <input id="m_search" name="s" type="text" placeholder="Type and hit enter..." />
            <input class="search-submit" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" />
          </form>
        </section>
      </section>
      <!-- .grid_12 end --> 
    </section>
    <!-- .container_12 end --> 

  </section>
  <!-- #nav-container end -->
```

Comment: Why don’t you use `wp_nav_menu()`?

Comment: i dont know how to , can you help me with it so that the CSS Setting n other stuff are not disturbed. Can you please tell me how to embed that code?

Comment: Use a [custom walker](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14039/73) to create the output you need. There are many more examples on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the free [Multi-level Navigation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-level-navigation-plugin/) plugin which gives you full control over what links are shown in your navigation. It's really easy to install and provides a link to a visual editor so that you can style the dropdowns like the rest of your website.

Comment: thanks for your reply but as you can see my menu has icons in it to, if i install something directly it will eliminate the icon n all. which i dont know how to manually set. so it would b better if someone adds a loop to this one and get the thing working

Comment: Fair enough. However, I personally think that it would be better to use a plugin so that you can manage your navigation in a graphical user interface and not have to worry about the code. While you would lose your icons and styling initially, these could be added back in at a later date. Function over form is probably best in this case.